# How to make this SQL Query more dynamic and linear?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view named `VIEW_FORM_SALE_SUBMISSION_INFO`

I have query as

```
select a.FormSl 
from VIEW_FORM_SALE_SUBMISSION_INFO as a
where FormSl between convert(int,'113990') and convert(int,'1131000')
```

My objective:

1. I want to pass these two values inside the `convert()` function as a parameter
2. I want this query to be more linear, i.e. can I make these convertions earlier to this query so that I can use between operator without as simple as possible?

Comment: Why do you need the `convert`? If FormS1 is an int use `where FormSl between 113990 and 1131000`.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: I need to convert because between is not working for the comparison since my two strings are of variable length

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. If FormSl is `int` then you parameters should be `int`. If FormSl is not an `int` but you store integers you should change the data type of FormSl to `int`. If you have non integer values in FormSl you will get a conversion error with your query because FormSl is implicitly converted to integer.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Mikael, I am working on someone's hoalf daone work, where the formsl is generated by first 3 chars from one war data, and I appends a auto incremented number to it. Fisrt I was making it all formsl will be 7 chars by leftpadding with zero in my application, but in order to maintain his work unchanged I have to used both 6 characters e.g. 113999 and 1131000, since both are strings therefore while using between operator, I either has to Lpad with zero or convert to integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
select a.FormSl 
from VIEW_FORM_SALE_SUBMISSION_INFO as a
where FormSl between @param1 and @param2
```

Where `@param1` and `@param2` are integer parameters?

Answer (score 1):

To parameterise this, you could make a table valued function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunction (@lower_bound AS VARCHAR(32), @upper_bound AS VARCHAR(32))
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
select a.FormSl 
from VIEW_FORM_SALE_SUBMISSION_INFO as a
where FormSl between convert(int,@lower_bound) and convert(int,@upper_bound)


SELECT * FROM dbo.myFunction('11111', '22222')
```

In terms of optimising the Convert, what you have is as optimal as it will get.

If you want to improve it further, don't pass in strings, pass int integers in the first place.